# How to move output files created from awk to a specific location?

Tags: awk

```
awk -v date="${R_Date}" -F"|" 'NR==1 {h=substr($0, index($0,$5)); next} 
            {file=""$1""$2"_"$3"_"$4"_"date".csv"; print (a[file]++?"": "AA9 "date"" ORS h ORS) substr($0, index($0,$5)) > file} 
             END{for(file in a) print "EOF " a[file] > file}' "${Src_Dir}/${log}"
```

I have an awk code like above. After running it it will create some outputs. But the problem is the output will be created at the location where I run the code. Is it possible I can specific a location for the outputs for this awk code? How do I do it? Appreciate if someone can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Just change your definition of `file`:

```
file="/home/myname/somedir/whatever/"$1""$2"_"$3"_"$4"_"date".csv"
```

Comment: but my definition for **file** is to specific how my output filename should looks like already. Is it possible to include both? Filename and specific location. Thanks

Comment: Thanks if you can help @Michael Vehrs